# PNG decoder returns extra bytes of pixel data

Tags: javascript, png

I'm trying to decode [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G82h3.png) using [UPNG.js](https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js), and getting the following output:

```
{ tabs: { pHYs: [ 2835, 2835, 1 ] },
  frames: [],
  width: 10,
  height: 1,
  depth: 16,
  ctype: 0,
  data:
   Uint8Array [
     255,255,
     255,255,
     255,255,
     255,255,
     255,255,
     253,23,
     252,204,
     252,130,
     252,56,
     255,255,
     255 
  ] }
```

The first 20 entries of the `data` array make sense, since each pixel is represented by 2 bytes. However, we get one extra byte. I've tested the first twenty bytes against gimp, so I know I'm getting the right pixel values. In larger images, we get one extra byte per row of pixels. I can go through the decoded pixel data and remove each last byte before I do any further processing, but I'm uncomfortable with removing possibly useful information I may need for encoding the resulting image.

I tried using other image processing libraries, but I can't find any alternative that both works in the browser, and doesn't convert the image to 8 bit RGBA behind the scenes.

Also, I know that the endianness of the `TypedArrays` is most likely little endian, while the endianness of the reference image is most likely big endian. I'm currently manually flipping the bytes in the `Uint8Array` before converting it to `Uint16Array`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the library's issues page, [here](https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js/issues/30).